# Strange thing during committing changes with git

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

So, I am on elementary os. I type git commit. Sublime text opens up with 1st line empty rest lines starting with # i.e. comments telling me what to do.I type my message. I save the file. I exit the editor. I run git status.What the heck?My file is still in the staging area and not committed.I try git commit -m "My message over here".This works absolutely fine. But the above message doesn't seem to work at all!!

Comment: I just tried this locally and it worked for me.  My guess is that either you didn't really stage any files or your editor has some bizarre quirks to it.

Comment: I had a file in the staging area or why else would i say that that file was "still in the staging area" .I can make  a video and post it if you want.

Comment: I have never experienced this error.  All I can suggest is that you try to see if maybe there is some configuration step you can do to integrate Git with your Sublime editor.  It could be something as simple as a permissions problem (e.g. Sublime tells Git to commit the message, but Git refuses, failing silently).

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to do so. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: How have you configured the editor? Type `git config --global -l` and find a line starting with `core.editor` (and anything else that seems relevant) and include that in your question.

Comment: More wierd things happening. Now it shows "Aborting commit due to empty commit message." Even when I write a message . Since I was not sure wherther to put the message in quotes or not I have tried everything without quotes, single quotes, double quotes but the same error message is appearing which never did before in any of the above cases.

Comment: core.editor=subl

Answer (score 1):

Getting the error message "Aborting commit due to empty commit message." is symptomatic of having configured a non-blocking call as the editor.

Git will run the command to start the editor, but the command returns immediately, so git immediately checks the commit message file, before you have had time to enter anything.

You need to configure a blocking call as the core.editor. It seems [subl documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/command_line/command_line.html) mentions a `-w` flag which should
cause the `subl` command to block until files have been closed. Try configuring "subl -w" as your core.editor instead.

Comment: Ok everything seems to working except for these warnings:                                 Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(sublime_text:3993): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(sublime_text:3993): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(sublime_text:3993): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(sublime_text:3993): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: I have never used subl editor myself, but just googling the error message is usually a good idea. Doing this, it seems that warning is discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/66361